# php check if THIS class implements an interface, not its parents

Tags: php, oop, interface

Is it possible to get the interfaces a specific class directly implements, and not the inherited ones of its parents?

For example, given these classes:

```php
interface Searchable {}

class Post implements Searchable {}

class Post_Deleted extends Post {}
```

This is how I am checking it at the moment:

```php
class Search {
    protected function _getClassesToSearch() {
        $classes_to_search = array();
        $declared_classes = get_declared_classes();
        foreach ($declared_classes as $class) {
            $implements = class_implements($class);
            if ($implements && in_array('Searchable', $implements)) {
                $classes_to_search[] = $class;
            }
        }
        return $classes_to_search;
    }
}
```

But `class_implements()` returns true for both `Post` and `Post_Deleted`, so I need to check if exactly THIS class implements an interface.

Comment: Look at `ReflectionClass::getInterfaces()`. Not sure off the top of my head whether it considers parents or not, but check it out.

Comment: How about `$all_impl = class_implements($class); $parent_impl = class_implements(get_parent_class($class)); $my_impl = array_diff($all_impl, $parent_impl);`?

Comment: I'd question why you need to do this? The whole point of the interface/class inheritence system is that you shouldn't need to know that kind of detail. If a class implements an interface, however far down the chain, then it implements it. If you're trying to find out details like this, then it implies you're trying to do something that probably doesn't need to be done or could be done in a much better way. Maybe with a bit more background, we could help guide you onto a better path.

Comment: I find it strange that you wan't to discriminate between implementors. If `Post_Deleted` extends `Post` it's searchable by contract. So if you're deciding to ignore interface implementation. Why use an interface in the first place.

Comment: If a parent implements an interface, so does its children. That's the nature of inheritance. It looks more like you'll have to find a different mechanism to discriminate between Post_Deleted and Post.

Comment: I think you are right. Interfaces may not be the best approach to solve my problem. I think I will still use the Searchable interface, which makes all implementing classes searchable by default, but add a static boolean property `$searchable` which can be overridden in child classes and checked in Search::_getClassesToSearch().

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the reservations made by others in the comments to your question, that what you're trying to do is probably based in a misunderstanding of inheritance, I think the code below will do what you want... Question is, should you be solving this problem at all?

How about something like this?

```
class Search {

    public function _getClassesToSearch() {

        $declared_classes = get_declared_classes();
        $classes_to_search = array_filter($declared_classes, function($class) {
            $ownInterfaces = class_implements($class);
            $parent = get_parent_class($class);
            if($parent) {
                $parentInterfaces = class_implements($parent);
            } else {
                $parentInterfaces = array();
            }

            $diff = array_diff($ownInterfaces, $parentInterfaces);
            $found = in_array('Searchable', $diff);
            return $found;
    });

    return $classes_to_search;
}

}
```